# Regular Expressions or BeautifulSoup - Varying Cases

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have 3 strings I am looking to retrieve that are characterized by the presence of two words: `section` and `front`. I'm terrible with regex.

```
contentFrame wsj-sectionfront economy_sf
contentFrame wsj-sectionfront business_sf
section-front markets
```

How can I match both of these words using one regular expression? This will be used to match the contents of a html page parsed by BeautifulSoup.

**UPDATE:**

I want to extract the main body of a webpage (https://www.wsj.com/news/business) that has the `div` tag:  [Main Content Housing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH2qa.png). For some reason, BeautifulSoup isn't recognizing the highlighted class attribute using:

```
wsj_soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'contentFrame wsj-sectionfront business_sf')
# Returns []
```

I'm trying to stay in BeautifulSoup as much as possible, but if regex is the way to go I will use that. From there I will more than likely search using the `contents` attribute to search for relevant keywords, but if anyone has a better idea of how to approach it please share.

Comment: If it's BeautifulSoup and you don't know regex, why not stick to something you know and pass a `lambda text: 'section' in text and 'front' in text` to BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @Aran-Fey That works beautifully, but I can't extract what I need (which is my fault given that there are a lot more class attributes that use `section` and `front` than I expected). Stay tuned for an update.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to use two separate lookaheads which check for each of these words:

```
^(?=.*section)(?=.*front).*$
```

### Demo